# Image slide runs wild after manual selecting image

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add the automatic part of the image slider, and I scroll manually, the image slider runs wild. Can someone fix that if you scroll manually, the slider goes like normal or the automatic part stops. Because its not good if the images go as fast as they go when you select an image manually. I have also the problem that my first image isn't loading or something, maybe that can be fixed aswell.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 10000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98);
  width: 75%;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.dots {
  background-color: rgba(23, 14, 13, 0.97);
  width: 75%;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -24px;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="selectie.html"><img src="images/vpersie.jpg" style="width:100%"/>

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="contact.html"><img src="images/logo-groot.png" style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="geschiedenis.html"><img src="images/logo-groot.png" style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div class="dots" style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing I noticed were the `<a>` tags in the slides not being closed. That would be the first thing to do.

Comment: You also have two `showSlides` functions. The latter function would overwrite the former function. Either turn it into a single function or remove the one you don't need.